# Java remove trailing 0's

Tags: java

Hi I have a string in java that goes like this:

"742706t000gf4604008264468468400000000000000000000000"

How would I remove all the trailing 0's at the end but leaving the ones in between?

Thanks!

Comment: `value.replaceAll("0+$", "");` or with [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripEnd%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) with the `"$"` character that indicates string's end, and the [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method

```
str = str.replaceAll("0+$", "")
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The 0's are still there. It is a hexString formed from a byte array.

Comment: @Shiv Strings are immutable. `str = str.replaceAll("0+$", "");` works for me.

Comment: @Shiv what @ZouZou means is you should reassign the result of `str.replaceAll("0+$", "")` to a variable - it creates a NEW string without the zeros, and it does NOT modify the old string

Comment: Well it is a hex binary string made from a byte array. Does it make a difference?

Comment: That's what I did. `String hexReply2  = hexReply1.replaceAll("0+$", "");`

Comment: @Shiv Then your `hexReply2` might have some hidden character or chracters you ignored (new lines? spaces?), those can be trimmed using `str.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "")`, for example.

Comment: @Shiv Also, your string contains `g` - which is not hexadecimal character, are you sure you are getting that string properly?

Comment: @amit The code I pasted isn't actually what it is, the actual thing is massive... Also I'm sure there isn't hidden chars.